# How to grab the first instance of a double-ordered pair of columns in a data frame?

Tags: r, sorting

I have cluster data for several items that also have a rank associated with them. The clusters and ranked data frame looks like this:

```
   clus   rank
A    1    1
B    1    3
C    1    5
D    2    4
E    2    6
F    3    9
G    3    8
H    3    7
```

I want to grab only the first name and rank in each cluster, but only that single item in each cluster, so that I get:

```
A    1
D    4
F    9
```

I can do this with some for loops but there must be a better way. Suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
df[!duplicated(df$clus), "rank", drop = FALSE]
#  rank
#A    1
#D    4
#F    9
```

or `df[!duplicated(df$clus),]` if you want to keep all columns.

The same approach could be done in dplyr and data.table of course.

Answer (score 3):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(clus) %>% 
   slice(1)
```

Or

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, head(.SD, 1L), clus]
```

To output only the "rank" column

```
setDT(df)[, list(rank=rank[1L]), clus][,clus:=NULL][]
```

If you need to preserve the row names

```
 df[with(df, ave(seq_along(clus), clus,
              FUN=seq_along)==1),'rank', drop=FALSE]
```

Answer (score 3):

Could also try `tapply` or `aggregate` (though those won't preserve row names...)

```
with(df, tapply(rank, clus, head, 1))
```

Or

```
aggregate(rank ~ clus, df, head, 1)
```

Comment: An option for preserving the row names would be  `df[with(df, c(TRUE,clus[-1]!=clus[-nrow(df)])),'clus', drop=FALSE]`